# can ufunc can calculate item iterate using numpy?

Tags: python, numpy

numpy is great,and ufunc and use to calculate on every item.

I want to calculate some data on the item,the calculate based on the neighbor of the item,so I want to get the item value and the neighbor's value when using self defined ufunc on every item,how to get the index of item when using ufunc?

here is my code:

```
//data is a ndarry type
def calc1(data,k,t):
    count = 0
    while count<t:
        for i in xrange(data.shape[0]):
            for j in xrange(data.shape[1]):
                if i == 0:
                    im = data.shape[0]-1
                else:
                    im = i-1
                if i == data.shape[0]-1:
                    ip = 0
                else:
                    ip = i+1
                if j == 0:
                    jm = data.shape[1]-1
                else:
                    jm = j-1
                if j == data.shape[1]-1:
                    jp = 0
                else:
                    jp = j+1
                data[i,j] = data[i,j]*exp(k*log(data[i,j]-k*log(data[i,jm])))+data[im,j]*exp(k*log(data[im,j])-k*log(data[im,jm]))+data[ip,j]*exp(k*log(data[ip,j])-k*log(data[ip,jp]))
        count += 1
        print count
    print data
```

calc is calculate the new data[i,j],and the calculate will apply to all the item in the matrix,so I think ufunc will help.

I make is using loop,but I think ufunc will be more elegent.

ufunc can apply some calculate on single item,so can I write a ufunc to my job?

Comment: You can write a generalized ufunc to do this. A usual ufunc is element wise, so it cannot handle it.

Comment: You can make shifted copies of `data` with `np.roll`. Then the iterations of `i` and `j` can be eliminated.